# collapsable description using jquery but with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am iterating through a db of upcoming 'Guides'. Each guide comes with description that can be somewhat long and takes up a lot of space. So, I attempted to implement the bootstrap 'collapse' function however it doesn't cater for dynamically generated content, (each data toggle thingy needs to be unqiue.. no?) so when I press the button on one it only activates one.

```
<% if @guide.any? %>    
<% @guide.each do |guide| %>
    <div class="guide-list col-md-5">
        <h2 class='guide-title'><%= guide.title %></h2>
        <h4 class='guide-date'>From <%= guide.date_starting.strftime("%B %d") %> to <%= guide.date_ending.strftime("%B %d") %></h4>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <%= image_tag guide.image(:med), :class => 'guide-image' %>
            <% if guide.description.empty? %>
                <h4>No description available</h4>
            <% else %>
                <p class='guide-description'><%= guide.description %></p>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <h4><%= guide.extra_info %></h4>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<h1>PLEASE COME BACK SOON </h1>
<% end %>
```

I have this code which I used in a previous app, I have spent ages trying to configure it for my current app but i just cant! My Javascript leaves a lot to be desired.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $(".comment-link").on("click", function(event) {
    var commentArea, postUrl;
    event.preventDefault();
    postUrl = $(this).data("post-url");
    commentArea = $(this).closest('.comment-price').find('.comments');
    return $.get(postUrl, function(post) {
      post.comments.forEach(function(comment) {
        return commentArea.html("<li>" + comment.content + "</li> - comment added @ " + comment.added + " by " + comment.username);
      });
      if (commentArea.is(':visible')) {
        return commentArea.slideUp();
      } else {
        return commentArea.slideDown();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: if you need it to be unique why not just tack on the guide id or similar to the class?

Comment: as i said, i dont really know what any of that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to do it by using the bootstrap.js collapse in the end.
I just dynamically created the id link.

```
             <div class="accordion" id="categories">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="  #info_<%= guide.id %>">
                        <h2 class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></h2>
                    </a>
                    <div id="info_<%= guide.id %>" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="acccordion-inner">
                            <% if guide.description.empty? %>
                                    <h4>No description available</h4>
                                <% else %>
                                    <p class='guide-description'><%= guide.description %></p>
                                <% end %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your issue is that you need to specify which area to toggle when you click the trigger.  The best way to handle this is with the jQuery parent() method.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // The jQuery selectors you want to use as triggers
  var selectors = $('.guide-list .guide-title');
  selectors.click(function() {
    var selector = $(this);  // The element that was clicked
    var parent = selector.parent(); // The parent element of that element
    var target = parent.find('.guide-description'); // The element to expand/collapse
    if(target.is(':visible')) {
      target.slideUp();
    } else {
      target.slideDown();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that the <h4>No description available</h4> when there is a lack of a description, might qualify as a description... but that's probably me just being picky

Comment: Thanks for your quick helpful reply...and then the rails markup would be a stubbed link_to the comments?

Comment: You can put anything you want in the rails markup, really.  In the .click() function, $(this) is the jquery selector for the element that was clicked.  Use $(this).parent() to access the container for the clicked element, or .parent().parent(), until you've gone up enough levels.  From that element, use .find() to select the element you want to show or hide.

Comment: <%= link_to 'Description', guide.description %>
But that's what I am unsure about. How do prevent this from being a link and somethign that exapands and retracts on click?